# How does South Korean football league work?

Tags: football, relegations

When I see this standings of the South Korean football league,

https://www.soccerstats.com/latest.asp?league=southkorea

I see the Championship group and the Relegation group.

What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top division league of South Korea consists of 12 teams.
They play 33 games first in a round-robin format, three games with each team.
Then the teams are split into two groups, one with the top six teams and the other with the bottom six teams.

They play five more games within the split group so the total is 38 games.

As of 2022, the top team in the Championship group goes to the AFC Champions League group stage, and the 2nd and the 3rd team go to the AFC Champions League qualification play-off.
The bottom team in the Relegation group (overall 12th) is relegated to the K League 2 in the next season.
The 4th and 5th teams in the Relegation Group (overall 10th and 11th)  play a promotion-relegation play-off game with teams from K League 2.

Comment: In addition, the winner of the Korean FA Cup has a spot in the AFC Champions League group stage. If they rank 1st, 2nd, or 3rd in the K League 1, the spots for the AFC Champions League go to the next ranked teams in the League.

Comment: If the FA Cup winners ranked 3rd in the League, then 2nd and 4th ranked teams go to the Qualfication play-off, right?

Comment: @JohnKim Exactly.

Comment: I believe this is the same format used in the Scottish Premiership, so it's not entirely unheard of.